# Binary instrumentation with Python

Tags: binary-analysis

I'm interested in performing (dynamic) binary instrumentation using Python to be able to analyze the binary by instructions during execution for

- Windows
- Linux

  Can someone suggest such tool/framework? Does it even exist or possible?

Comment: Man ... that is going to be hella slow.

Comment: I know, but currently I do not really care :)

Answer (score 9):

From https://code.google.com/p/processtap/ -

> **ProcessTap** is a dynamic tracing framework for analyzing closed
>   source-applications. ProcessTap is inspired by [DTrace](http://opensolaris.org/os/community/dtrace/) and [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/),
>   but it is specific for analyzing closed-source user-space
>   applications. ProcessTap leverages dynamic binary instrumentation to
>   intercept the events of interest (e.g., function calls, system call,
>   memory accesses, and conditional control transfers). Although the
>   current implementation relies on [PinTool](http://www.pintool.org/), alternative back-ends for
>   instrumentation (e.g., [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/), [Qemu](http://www.qemu.org/), or [DynamoRIO](http://code.google.com/p/dynamorio/)) can be used. The
>   language used in ProcessTap for writing scripts to instrument
>   applications is [Python](http://www.python.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Despite being an afternoon hack, [this static binary instrumenter](https://github.com/pgoodman/Python-Binary-Instrumenter) might get you part way there. However, consider these crucial limitations:

- It's not dynamic insofar as it runs at compile time, not at runtime.
- It is also not comprehensive, in the sense that shared and dynamically loaded libraries will not be instrumented by this.
- It provides no mechanisms for maintaining state, except by linking in your own code (exampled in the `gc` directory and `Makefile`). There isn't a good way of connecting instrumentation to that code, except by perhaps declaring and using an `extern` symbol whose mangled name you know.

BUT, it is in python ;-)